# Python Scenario Building Through Input Classification

Tags: python

I'm trying to build an efficient way to classify 4 different input variables and output them together to build a scenario 's', using Python.  I can't seem to find the best way to do it.  Any help here would be greatly appreciated.  I've scoured all related posts and can't find an exact answer.

Basically I want to output:

```
scenario s = (w: 'value_of_w', x: 'value_of_x', y: 'value_of_y', z: 'value_of_z')
```

where the values will be either 'low', 'medium', or 'high' given the below e.g.:

```
if w < 10:
  value of w = 'low'
elif 10 < w < 50:
  value of w = 'med'
elif w > 50:
  value of w = 'high'

if x < 5:
  value of w = 'low'
elif 5 < x < 15:
  value of w = 'med'
elif x > 15:
  value of x = 'high'

if y < 25:
  value of y = 'low'
elif 25 < y < 75:
  value of w = 'med'
elif y > 75:
  value of y = 'high'

if z < 3:
  value of z = 'low'
elif 3 < z < 7:
  value of z = 'med'
elif z > 7:
  value of z = 'high'
```

The actual values of w, x, y, z to come in through an input form.

Comment: What have you tried? What is a "scenario" and why is it called thus? Is this data being fed to somewhere else? If so, can you provide documentation for the required format?

Comment: Please use four spaces for indention in Python. And `value of` is no correct Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Scenario(object):
  def __init__(self, w, x, y, z):
    self.val = {}
    self.val['w'] = self.value(w,10,50)
    self.val['x'] = self.value(x,5,15)
    self.val['y'] = self.value(y,25,75)
    self.val['z'] = self.value(z,3,7)
  def value(self, v, l, u):
    if (v < l):
      return "low"
    if (u > v >= l ):
      return "med"
    if (v >= u):
      return "high"
  def __str__(self):
    return "scenario = w: " + self.val['w'] + " x: " + self.val['x'] + " y: " + self.val['y'] + " z: " + self.val['z']
```

You'd use this as: `s = Scenario(15,945,2,18)` and then `print s`, or anything else that requires a string, which would output in the format you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, where exactly you problem lies: Would it help to use a simple `dict` for your scenario? Like:

```
s = {}
if w < 10:
  s['w'] = 'low'
elif 10 <= w < 50:
  s['w'] = 'med'
elif w >= 50:
  s['w'] = 'high'

if x < 5:
  s['x'] = 'low'
elif 5 <= x < 15:
  s['x'] = 'med'
# ... and so on
```

Note that I replaced part of the `<`with `<=` (and `>` with `>=`), so you get scenarios for *all* values of `w`, `x`, `y`, `z`.

Comment: I'm looking for it to output specifically as key-value pair like: scenario = (w='low',x=high',y='med',z='low').